# Changing language without being redirected to the home page

Tags: php, indexing, twig

As many, I am having problem staying on the same page when changing language.
I have read many questions and answers but they didn't work for me. I tried to work it out, but I can't.

I am a student and I started coding this year. I work with Twig and it confuses me more.

Here is my php file for detecting the language

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['lng'])){
     $lng = $_GET['lng'];
     if($lng !== '' && ($lng === 'fr' || $lng === 'en'))
      $_SESSION['langue'] = $lng;
    }
    if(isset($_SESSION['langue'])) $userLang = $_SESSION['langue'];
    else $userLang = 'en';

  ?>
```

In the index.php I have written

```
$page = "index";
if( isset ($_GET['page']) ) $page = $_GET['page'];
$pagePHP = "home";
switch( $page )
{
  case "whatwedo" : $pagePHP = "whatwedo";   $current = "whatwedo";   break;
      default : $pagePHP = "home";  $current = "home";   break;
}
$view->setVar('currentPage', $page);
include "pages/$pagePHP.php";
```

And this is my layout.html.twig

```
<div id="menulangue">
         <a href="index.php?lng=fr" title="Français"><div class="btnlanguess">Français</div></a>
         <a href="index.php?lng=en" title="English"><div class="btnlangue">English</div></a>
</div>
```

I tried to change the a href's link in several ways. The last two I remember:

1. a href="index.php?page={{ currentPage }}?lng=fr"
2. a href="{{ currentPage }}?lng=fr"

But it doesn't work. My url of the index is index.php?lng=en and of another page(no matter if it is in English or French) is index.php?page=whatwedo.
In the above cases, when clicked on the change of language, not only it returns to the index page but the url of the index page become as follows

case 1. index.php?page=equipe?lng=fr and in that case if chosen another page it continues to the language by default.

case 2. whatwedo?lng=fr and the page is not found: Not Found

The requested URL /APL/whatwedo was not found on this server.

Comment: was the session started?

Comment: Yes. I have that on the start of the index.php <?php
session_start();

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

Comment: `index.php?page=equipe?lng=fr` - the second argument should use `&` and not `?`.

Comment: whatwedo&lng=fr I have tried it with &-it says Not Found

The requested URL /APL/whatwedo&lng=fr was not found on this server.

Comment: and also `equipe` where is that being defined?

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, Fred! You are a genius-I have change in the first case the ? with & and it worked perfectly! Thank you very much!

Comment: Oh, you're most welcome :-) *Cheers*

Comment: I posted a (community wiki) answer below which you can mark as correct, to close the question.

Comment: *Welcome to Stack!*

Comment: I marked. Thank you once again!

Comment: Always a pleasure, *cheers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as a community wiki answer, seeing it was solved in comments.

Me:

> *"index.php?page=equipe?lng=fr - the second argument should use & and not ?"*

OP:

> *"Wow, thank you very much, Fred! You are a genius-I have change in the first case the ? with & and it worked perfectly! Thank you very much!"*